# Problemas con el geom_smooth de ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2

Por alguna razón no logro que aparezca el geom_smooth agregado a un geom_point, que sí grafico sin problema:

```
ggplot(data= filter(df, GRANJA == 30, DIAS <100, !is.na(dpi)),
       aes(x = dpi, y = OD_SUERO, group = dpi)) + 
  geom_point(size = 0.7) +
  geom_smooth()
```

[image: geom_point(9]

Las variables x = dpi e y = OD_SUERO son numéricas (ambas tipo 'dbl').

¿Alguien me podría orientar sobre la causa?

Saludos.